# Why is my function which is supposed to return an array with no dupes removing non-dupe values too?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

So I've got an array of arrays, each with a value and a name corresponding to said value.
Here I hard-coded it, but in reality it's not.

I have a function which is supposed to return the array it was given, but with only ONE of each value. However, the function is removing other values too. Here is the code:

```js
const scorersArr = [
  [2, 'Lewandowski'],
  [1, 'Gnarby'],
  [2, 'Lewandowski'],
  [1, 'Hummels'],
]

const returnNoDupes = (arr) => {
  let returnArr = arr;
  for (const arrVal1 of arr) {
    for (const arrValLoop of arr) {
      if (arrVal1 === arrValLoop) returnArr.splice(arrVal1, 1)
    }
  }
  return returnArr;
}

console.log(returnNoDupes(scorersArr)); //. Expected: [[2, "Lewandowski"], [1, "Hummels"], [1, "Gnarby"]]
```

I know that the bug has something to do with the fact that I have a 2D array, as this function works on a 1D array but I can't quite put my finger on what it is.

Comment: This function doesn't work at all. The basic problem is you're comparing every item against every item so you also compare every item against itself and then remove it. `if(arr[n] === arr[n]) arr.splice(n, 1);` But your code also has another bug due to you removing items from the array you're iterating over.

Comment: You should check for `arrVal1[1]`  and  `arrValLoop[1]` for splicing.

Comment: Ankit - I tried that but it became even more broken.

Comment: Thomas - Thanks a lot, I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: `scorersArr.filter((a, i, arr) => i === arr.findIndex(b => b[1] === a[1]))`

Comment: This works! Actually, the only reason I didn't use ```Array.propotype.filter()``` was because it was giving me a huge headache whenever I tried.

Comment: @Thomas - if my code is completely wrong, how come it works for a 1D array?

Comment: @siddhu-learn-javascript it's like the broken clock that shows the correct time twice a day. It does not work for 1D arrays in general, it produces the correct result by chance for the specific array you entered.

Comment: Oh yeah I was lucky...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this,

```js
  const scorersArr = [
  [2, 'Lewandowski'],
  [1, 'Gnarby'],
  [2, 'Lewandowski'],
  [1, 'Hummels'],
  ]

  const returnNoDupes = (arr) => {
  for (let i =0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){
    for (let j =0 ; j<arr.length ; j++) {
    if (arr[i][1] === arr[j][1] && i!==j){ 
        arr.splice(j, 1)
    }
   }}
   return arr;
 }
 console.log(returnNoDupes(scorersArr));
```

Comment: This doesn't work - the expected result is```[[2, "Lewandowski"], [1, "Hummels"], [1, "Gnarby"]]```

Comment: I have just updated it, now check it. It wasn't updated at that time.

Comment: @Ankit your splicing is still broken. Try `const scorersArr = [[2, 'Lewandowski'], [1, 'Gnarby'], [1, 'Gnarby'], [2, 'Lewandowski'], [2, 'Lewandowski'], [1, 'Gnarby'], [1, 'Gnarby'], [2, 'Lewandowski'], [1, 'Hummels']]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const scorersArr = [
  [2, 'Lewandowski'],
  [1, 'Gnarby'],
  [2, 'Lewandowski'],
  [1, 'Hummels'],
]

const duplicatesRemoved = Array.from(new Set(scorersArr.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse)

console.log(duplicatesRemoved)
```

A simplified/non-advanced JS solution

```
var scorersArr = [
  [2, 'Lewandowski'],
  [1, 'Gnarby'],
  [2, 'Lewandowski'],
  [1, 'Hummels'],
];

var nonDupesStringArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < scorersArr.length - 1; i++) {
 for (let j = 0; j < scorersArr.length; j++) {
   let currentArrayString = JSON.stringify(scorersArr[i]);
   let currentComporisonArrayString = JSON.stringify(scorersArr[j]);

   let isADuplicate = currentArrayString !== currentComporisonArrayString;
   let isNotInDuplicatesArray = nonDupesStringArray.indexOf(currentComporisonArrayString) < 0;

   if (isADuplicate && isNotInDuplicatesArray)
    nonDupesStringArray.push(JSON.stringify(scorersArr[j]))
 }
}

// convert strings back into array
var nonDupes = []
for (let i = 0; i < nonDupesStringArray.length; i++) {
  nonDupes.push(JSON.parse(nonDupesStringArray[i]))
}

console.log(nonDupes)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I'm not _that_ advanced in javascript yet, though to your credit it does work

Comment: As a function: `const returnNoDupes = arr => Array.from(new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse)`

Comment: I haven't got a clue as to how that works.

Comment: @siddhu-learn-javascript I have added a non-advance JS solution as well. Let me know if I can help you more.

Comment: @siddhu-learn-javascript It is not rocket science. It is just using [a Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to de-duplicate the array after converting the nested array to and from JSON

Comment: I understand what a set is, but I do not understand or see the need of the JSON part

Comment: @siddhu-learn-javascript

The arrays are basically objects in JS. And comparing two arrays with same values result in false ([1] == [1] is false). But comparing two equal strings results in true ("[1]" == "[1]" is true). So we convert and array to string (using JSON.stringify) for comparison and then convert it back to array (using JSON.parse) once we have removed the duplicates. I hope this explains the solution.

Comment: Ohhh thanks I didn't know that before.